# JS/Jquery populating array then sending via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using JQuery UI's sortable to sort a list `#sortable` by dragging each element in to the desired order.

I am storing the `id` of the item in the `li` `id` attribute (I am aware this is invalid), and the `order` of the element in the `rel` attribute.

So for example:

```
<li id="23" rel="1">First</li>
<li id="20" rel="2">Second</li>
<li id="24" rel="3">Third</li>
```

My code successfully updates the `rel`when I drag and drop a `li` element - this is fine.

Now, when I click the submit button, I would like to send an array of data via AJAX to my script, which will perform the update queries. Ideally, the `id` will be the `key` and the `rel` value will be the `value.

```
array(
       23 => 1
       20 => 2
       24 => 3
)
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   //array
   var the_data = [];

   $('#sortable li').each(function() {

        the_data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr('rel');

   });

   console.log(the_data);         
});
```

I'm getting `undefined` lots of times in FireBug, but if I expand it, all the values are there, could someone please explain what is wrong? It makes sense to me, at least.

What is the best way to send an array of data to AJAX? I have read about Jquery's `.param()` and also `serialize`

Are there any best practices for this?

My ajax:

```
myData=Jquery.param(the_data); //serialize the array?
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/update_order/",
                data: myData,
                success: function(msg) {
                alert('Updated'); 
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                  alert(msg);       
                }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't write the code myself.  Just use the functionality inherit in jQuery UI Sortable.

Tie in a stop event function and use .sortable('serialize') to get the list in the new order in a format easily passed through Ajax.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for jQuery UI's sortable, it shows 2 methods to get an array of the ID's back for your purpose.  I'd look specifically at the [serialize](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize) method as it gets closer to what you want.  Especially if you can forgo the rel attribute and just move to an underscored id.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link correct to work on jquery sortable for ajax contents and binding to a update function see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naseeh/snx2j7z0/1/)

Javascript

```
$(function () {
$( '.contentLeft' ).sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
$("#log").html('update called');   }
});  });



$("#search").click(function() {
               loadDrop();               
           });

function loadDrop()
        {$.ajax({
                url:'/echo/html',
                success:function(){ 
                $("#trig").html('<div><ul id="sortable" class="contentLeft"><li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li><li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li></div>');
                test();
$(".contentLeft").sortable({opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move'});

                }
            });
        }
function test(){
$( '.contentLeft' ).sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', 
update: function() {
 $("#log2").html('update called via ajax');
}});
}
```